# Rendering a map on a Button Click - React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, dictionary

I am doing a weather app and so far so good.  I now want to render some extra information on a button click.  I have a 5 day forecast and want to then show each day's info.  I have filtered the data successfully but can't get my map of the data to then render.  Here is some of my code to show what I am trying to do (lots of console logs as I look to see whats working).  Thanks for any info you can give me.  Cheers,

This is from my componant that has the button (which is part of a map itself:

```
 return (
               <div> 
           <><motion.button onClick={() => Weather5day(forecast, noonCast.dt)}        className='weatherFSmall' initial={{ scale: 0 }} animate={{ scale: 1 }} transition={{ delay: (1.3 + (index     / 2)) }} key={index}>
```

I plan to tidy it up late w.r.t the motion element.

Here is a componant I am then calling (some is commented out as they don't work properly so I'll work on that later.  Thanks in advace for any tips.  The data I need does pass.

```
 export function Weather5day (fiveDayData,forecastArray) {
 console.log(fiveDayData);
 let fiveDayArry=[]
 let k=0
 console.log(forecastArray)   
 for (let i=0; i<fiveDayData.length;i++) {
 if (fiveDayData[i].dt == forecastArray) {
    if (i-3<0){k = 0}else {k=i-3}
    fiveDayArry = fiveDayData.slice(k,i+5)
   /* console.log(fiveDayD)  */
}
```

}
console.log(fiveDayArry)

```
return (
<div className='forecastContainer'>  
    {fiveDayArry.map((fiveDayArry) => {
        /* let windData = fiveDayArry.wind.deg */
        /* let windDir = WindCalc(windData) */
        
            <div className='weatherFSmall'>
                <h4>Avg Temp: {Math.round(fiveDayArry.main.temp)}°C</h4>
                    <h4>Weather: {fiveDayArry.weather[0].main}</h4>
                    <img src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${fiveDayArry.weather[0].icon}.png`} alt="Weather Icon" width="50" height="50" />
                    <h4>Wind Speed: {Math.round(fiveDayArry.wind.speed * 2.37)} mph</h4>
                    {/* <h4>Wind Direction {windData}</h4> */}
            </div>
      
    })}


  </div>
 )

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning the JSX on your map function, just add an extra return inside of your map and it should work.

See the example below:

```
export function Weather5day(fiveDayData, forecastArray) {
  console.log(fiveDayData)
  let fiveDayArry = []
  let k = 0
  console.log(forecastArray)
  for (let i = 0; i < fiveDayData.length; i++) {
    if (fiveDayData[i].dt == forecastArray) {
      if (i - 3 < 0) {
        k = 0
      } else {
        k = i - 3
      }
      fiveDayArry = fiveDayData.slice(k, i + 5)
      /* console.log(fiveDayD)  */
    }
  }
  console.log(fiveDayArry)

  return (
    <div className="forecastContainer">
      {fiveDayArry.map((fiveDayArry) => {
        /* let windData = fiveDayArry.wind.deg */
        /* let windDir = WindCalc(windData) */

        return (
          <div className="weatherFSmall">
            <h4>Avg Temp: {Math.round(fiveDayArry.main.temp)}°C</h4>
            <h4>Weather: {fiveDayArry.weather[0].main}</h4>
            <img
              src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${fiveDayArry.weather[0].icon}.png`}
              alt="Weather Icon"
              width="50"
              height="50"
            />
            <h4>Wind Speed: {Math.round(fiveDayArry.wind.speed * 2.37)} mph</h4>
            {/* <h4>Wind Direction {windData}</h4> */}
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quicl reply.  I just tried that, both adding a return where you said and full copy and paste of your suggestion.  I know it's difficuly to advise when you only have part of the pictutre.  In the componant that calls the 5day function I put this in it's return.  I think the issue is it doesnt render on click

Comment: </div>
            
            <Weather5day />
            
            </div>